# How do i know when recursive read file end?

Tags: node.js

I need to recursive read file to count words in a folder , how do i know when to end in asynchronous? 
It differ from [Node - how to wait on async operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452038/node-how-to-wait-on-async-operations)

```
function loop_file(folder) {
    fs.readdir(folder, function (err, files) {
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            var abs_path = path.join(folder, file);
            fs.stat(abs_path, function (err, stat) {
                if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    loop_file(abs_path)
                } else if (stat.isFile()) {
                    //proceess ???
                }
            })
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the async-foreach accepts another parameter as done-function. This will be called after the last Iteration has finished.

[source.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-foreach)